# Definir relacionamento entre tabelas no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Hoje necessitei criar uma tabela que tinha um proposito semelhante ao Adicionar a fila do netflix onde ficam salvos os filmes que o usuário deseja ver (na aplicação seriam armazenadas as urls videos e fotos), mais que depressa comecei a dar create table porem notei que esta havendo redundância de dados e a estética dela não estava legal, então algum membro já passou por um problema semelhante ou tem alguma ideia de como resolver com a menor quantidade de recursos possível? lembrando que mais de um usuario pode ter o mesmo filme na fila de reproduçã e o tamanho da fila é variavel

Imagens das Tabelas
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: a coluna `data` na tabela `VIDEOS` representa o que? A data que o vídeo foi cadastrado?

Comment: sim data de cadastramento do video

Comment: Qual o problema de estética que você está vendo? O que você quer saber? O que você tentou fazer para montar a tabela que falta? O enunciado do exercício não tem mais nenhuma informação relevante?

Comment: Pela lógica seria preciso uma tabela "n:m" usuarios_videos , relacionando os usuarios aos seus vídeos.

Comment: O problema é que quando criei a tabela fila de exibição os dados ficar duplicados entre as linhas, outro ponto é que a quantidade de filmes na fila de exibição é variavel EX: usuario com id:1 tem na fila os filmes com id:2, id:7, id: 4, id:3. usuario com id 2: tem na fila os filmes com id:5, id:7, id:8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aparentemente não vi nenhum problema nas suas tabelas, porém para fazer o que você quer é necessário criar mais uma, por exemplo:

```
TABELA LISTAS
| id | id_usuario | id_video |
```

Ai você teria algo desse tipo:

```
TABELA USUARIOS
| id  | login | pass |
|  1  | user1 |  123 |
|  2  | user2 |  abc |
|  3  | user3 |  1b3 |

TABELA VIDEOS (resumi ela)
| id  | titulo |      urlvideo       |
|  1  | Video1 | http://www.1.com.br |
|  2  | Video2 | http://www.2.com.br |

TABELA LISTAS
| id  | id_usuario | id_video |
|  1  |     1      |     1    |
|  2  |     2      |     2    |
|  3  |     3      |     1    |
|  4  |     3      |     2    |
```

Então você conseguiria a lista completa com usuários e videos assim:

```
SELECT
    usr.login,
    vdo.titulo,
    vdo.urlvideo
FROM
    LISTAS lst
    INNER JOIN USUARIOS usr ON (lst.id_usuario = usr.id)
    INNER JOIN VIDEOS vdo ON (lst.id_video = vdo.id)
```

Com o *select* acima, você poderia utilizar o `WHERE` e filtrar somente um usuário específico.

Somente para explicar um pouco mais, na tabela `VIDEOS`, os vídeos serão cadastrados uma única vez e poderão ser utilizados na lista de qualquer usuário sem a necessidade de cadastrá-los novamente. A tabela `LISTAS` será a responsável por relacionar os usuários com os vídeos, gerando assim sua lista ou fila, o que achar melhor.

Comment: Mas se por exemplo um usuario tivesse 20 videos na lista, ele teria 20 entradas na tabela, o que seria 20 linhas

Comment: ele teria 20 registros na tabela `LISTAS`, na minha resposta, o usuário com `id = 3` tem 2 registros, pois tem 2 vídeos em sua lista, já os de `id = 1` e `id = 2`, tem um registro cada na tabela `LISTAS`, resultado 4 registros no total

Comment: Mas alexandre nao há como economizar ? ja que um usuario no seu exemplo tem como ter multiplas entradas, logo se ele tivesse vinte videos na fila ele teria 20 entradas na tabela

Comment: se estamos falando que um usuário pode ter vários vídeos diferentes, não consigo visualizar outra forma, pode ser que alguém conheça melhor o `MySQL` e tenha outra visão!

Comment: Nesse caso o jeito usual de resolver é esse mesmo. Base de dados relacional é pra isso, para se trabalhar com um monte de linhas. Tem quem ponha tudo num campo só, com separadores, mas geralmente isso é sinal de problemas sérios de arquitetura.